# Serverfault orientated podcast

Tags: feature-request

The Stack overflow podcast has always been very tightly focussed on the SO community and programming related conversation. Obviously this is inevitable when the two presenters are both programmers, and I'm not complaining, there is SF and SU content included from time time.

However, it would be interesting if there could perhaps be a one off (or occasional) Serverfault orientated podcast, perhaps discussing some issues that are more related to to SysAdmin type things, and maybe getting in some of the top SysAdmin bloggers or high profile Sysadmins as guests.

I'm not saying there should be a new Serverfault podcast, or the existing one should focus more on Serverfault more often (although that would be nice) but a one off edition would be an acknowledgement of all the hard work people are doing on SF, and may perhaps encourage more users who've not heard about SF to use it.

Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has considered emailing/calling Jeff/Joel with some sysadmin related questions.

Answer (score 3):

[Podcast #75 guest stars Tom Limoncelli](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/podcast-75/) of Everything Sysadmin and regales you with a banging bucks' worth of sysadmin content on the Stack Overflow podcast series.

Comment: Very good point, I'd forgotten all about that one.